# Failed to create SQL script transfer with powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, smo

I've got next error when I'm trying to create database script:

> Exception calling "EnumScriptTransfer" with "0" argument(s): "Script
>   transfer failed. " At C:\temp\Test.ps1:126 char:5
>   +     $transfer.EnumScriptTransfer();
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FailedOperationException

Same script is working properly on the other computer. So I assume that the reason is in SQL server version, or rights.
Any ideas?

Code:

```
echo "Scripting database $dbname .."    
set-psdebug -strict
$ErrorActionPreference = "stop" # you can opt to stagger on, bleeding, if an error occurs
# Load SMO assembly, and if we're running SQL 2008 DLLs load the SMOExtended and SQLWMIManagement libraries
$ms='Microsoft.SqlServer'
$v = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( "$ms.SMO")
$ver = (($v.FullName.Split(','))[1].Split('='))[1];
$vtmp=$ver.Split('.')[0];
echo " SMO version is $ver"
if ($vtmp -ge 9) {
            echo " Running SQL 2008, load the SMOExtended .."
            [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("$ms.SMOExtended") | out-null
        }
$My="$ms.Management.Smo" #
$s = new-object ("$My.Server") $DataSource
if ($s.Version -eq  $null ){Throw "Can't find the instance $Datasource"}
$ver = $s.Version
echo " SQL Server version is $ver"
$db= $s.Databases[$Database]
if ($db.name -ne $Database){Throw "Can't find the database '$Database' in $Datasource"};
$transfer = new-object ("$My.Transfer") $db
if ($transfer -eq  $null ){Throw "Can't create transfer object"}
$transfer.Options.ScriptBatchTerminator = $true # this only goes to the file
$transfer.Options.ToFileOnly = $true # this only goes to the file
$transfer.Options.ScriptData = $true;
$transfer.Options.FileName = $BackupFile;
$tmp = $transfer.Options
echo " Transfer options are: $tmp"
echo "    $transfer"
$transfer.EnumScriptTransfer();
```

Output:

```
Scripting database MyDbName ..
 SMO version is 14.0.0.0
 SQL Server version is 14.0.1000
 Transfer options are: ScriptingOptions: ScriptBatchTerminator, ToFileOnly, SchemaQualify, WithDependencies, AllowSystem
Objects, AgentJobId, NoVardecimal, ScriptSchema, ScriptData, ScriptDataCompression, PrimaryObject
    Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Transfer
Exception calling "EnumScriptTransfer" with "0" argument(s): "Script transfer failed. "
At C:\temp\Test.ps1:126 char:5
+     $transfer.EnumScriptTransfer();
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FailedOperationException
```

Tried to add try-catch block, but this does not work. No idea why:

```
Try
{
 $transfer.EnumScriptTransfer();
}
Catch
{
 $msg = $_.Exception.Message;
 $innerMsg = $_.Exception.InnerException.Message;
echo $msg
echo $innerMsg 
throw;
}
```

Comment: Try enclosing the script in a try/catch and in the catch block, use `$_.Exception.Message` and `$_.Exception.InnerException.Message` to see if additional error details are available.

Comment: This does not print anything. And seems that try-catch does not work at all. No idea why

Comment: Didn't notice you have `$ErrorActionPreference = "stop"`. Change the value to either "Continue" or "SilentlyContinue" so that the script execution continues, executing the `catch` block.

Comment: I have the same error.  I did what you suggested and the error is still there, it just did not stop the script execution and kept running to the end